# Working with grep

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, curl

I am try to fetch all the links from `materialdesignicons.com`! I do the following:

```
curl -X GET https://materialdesignicons.com | grep -i "<link href=" | grep -v "<link href="
```

But it doesn't output anything. Everything works until `grep -v`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down:

1. Grab the web page

   ```
   curl -X GET https://materialdesignicons.com
   ```
2. Feed the results through a search (without regard to case) for the pattern `<link href=`

   ```
   grep -i "<link href="
   ```
3. Feed the next stage of results through a search for lines that *do not match* the pattern `<link href=`

   ```
   grep -v "<link href="
   ```

The result is that you'll only get matches for text matching `<link href=` where one or more of the letters are capitalised. For example

```
<link href=        # Will not match
<link HREF=        # Will match
<LinK HrEf=        # Will match
```

If you want to list all the `link href` values you could try this, which will match links that are not split across multiple lines:

```
curl -X GET https://materialdesignicons.com | grep -Po "(?<=link href=([\"'])).*?(?=\g1)"
```

It's not a particular pleasant regular expression so I'll try to break it down for you:

```
(?<=link href=([\"']))    # Look for "link href=" followed by either single or double quote
.*?                       # Match and output the shortest possible string until...
(?=\g1)                   # We have found a repeat of the quote we found earlier
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative grep solution is

`grep -iPo "(<link href=\")[^\"]*"`

The `[]`defines a character class which includes only a single character, a `"`, escaped (`\"`)for reasons I hope you appreciate, and then the class is negated `^` meaning "anything which isn't a `"`"

This translates as "find a case insensitive occurrence of `<link href="` then match all of the following characters until you find a `"` and then stop, but don't include the `"`".

Anyway, since @roaima beat me to a regex solution and I am repeatedly having it beaten into me that it is (apparently) not recommended to parse html with `grep`, I thought I'd also play with `xmllint` and the xpath (`//link/@href`) may be easier to grasp if you are unfamiliar with regex.

`xmllint --html --xpath "//link/@href" <( curl -X GET https://materialdesignicons.com )`

This tells `xmllint` to expect an `--html` document and uses `--xpath` expression `//link/@href` to select the `href` attributes within all the `link` tags.

However `xmllint` complains about the html downloaded from your url being not well formed, so we `pipe` it through `tidy` to correct it, suppressing any verbosity (`-q`) and discarding any error messages (`2>/dev/null`) before redirecting the well formed output to `xmllint`

`xmllint --html --xpath "//link/@href" <( curl -X GET https://materialdesignicons.com | tidy -q  2>/dev/null)`

This yields the `href` attributes still lovingly(?) wrapped in quotes

`href="/favicon.png" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300" href="styles/css/bootstrap.css" href="styles/app.css"`

A bit of post-processing needed to give the bare links, but now you have a choice of tools.

Comment: +1 for using `xmllint`; this is by far the cleaner solution